# Find the total bytes used by a bitmap in Flex

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flex3, bitmap

If I load a bitmap using a loader in Flex, I can use the loaderInfo.bytesTotal to get the size, total bytes used, of a bitmap.

If I create a bitmap in run time, how can I find out the size, the total bytes used, by that bitmap.

Please advice.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> var bitmapByteSize:int = bitmap.bitmapData.getPixels(bitmap.bitmapData.rect).length;

That might do the trick.

Comment: JStriedl, thanks for your reply.  I have tried a similar method before.
var byteArray:ByteArray =  _bitmap.bitmapData.getPixels(new Rectangle(0, 0, _bitmap.width, _bitmap.height));
_bitmapTotalBytes = byteArray.length;
However, _bitmapTotalBytes is much larger than the original jpg file, although I have already reduce the width and height.

Do you know why?  Thanks.

Comment: The jpeg format is compressed when stored on disk, and must be decompressed for display.  So, the length of the ByteArray will be much larger than the file, as it represents the pixel data in uncompressed, displayable format, NOT the original compressed JPEG file size.

Answer (score 3):

I think a better solution than the one above would be:

```
var bitmapByteSize:uint = bitmap.bitmapData.width * bitmap.bitmapData.height * 4;
```

This is because using the getPixels() method creates an additional ByteArray, so it's both slow and uses extra memory.

Comment: Thanks bslote. What is the meaning of " * 4 " in the equation.  I means why to multiple by 4 but not other number.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about the delayed response, michael. It's because there's four 8-bit channels in the BitmapData (RGB and alpha). So we take the number of pixels in the bitmap (width * height), then multiply it by the number of channels (4) times the number of bytes per channel (1) to get the total number of bytes in the bitmap.