# Getting number of bytes of a bitmap

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Goal is to show progress of jpeg encoding from bitmap. I have couple of bitmaps that need to be encoded. So I get the total number of bytes as was [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505054/find-the-total-bytes-used-by-a-bitmap-in-flex):

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < bitmaps.length; i++) 
{
    bmp = bitmaps[i];

    total_bytes += bmp.getPixels(bmp.rect).length;
}
```

Then I'm trying to show progress when doing asychronous encoding. I get a [ProgressEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/ProgressEvent.html) which gives me bytesLoaded. So I calculate the progress like so:

```
total_loaded_bytes += event.bytesLoaded;

var percentage:int = ((total_loaded_bytes / total_bytes) * 100);
```

However, `total_bytes` does not add up to `total_loaded_bytes`. Total bytes loaded is way highter.

Comment: Why don't you use the `event.bytesTotal` instead of `total_bytes`?

Comment: `event.bytesTotal` is just for specific image that is getting encoded at the moment. I have couple of images. So I need to get total size of images, add up total loaded and divide whatever is loaded by total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A wrong approach to use `bytesLoaded` property. This is not to be blandly added up, as this contains the total of already loaded bytes bu the `Loader` object that issued the event. And a wrong approach on getting total bytes too, you need to use `event.bytesTotal` from within the progress event listener, since you are loading bytes, not pixels. Even if you are *uploading*. Also, the exact progress may be totally unavailable for asynchronous encoding, you are only displaying the uploading/downloading progress.

Update: to receive an accumulated progress, do something like this:

```
var loaders:Array=[]; // array of loaders. Fill manually
var progress:Array=[]; // fill with zeroes alongside loaders, should be same size
function updateProgress(e:ProgressEvent):void {
    var loader:Loader=e.target as Loader;
    if (!loader) return; // or skip type coercion, we just need the reference
    var i:int=loaders.indexOf(loader); // now get an index from array
    if (i<0) return; // not found, drop it
    progress[i]=e.bytesLoaded; // and update progress array with new value
    // now sum up progress array and divide by aggregated bytesTotal
    // this one is up to you
}
```

Comment: `event.bytesTotal` is just for specific image that is getting encoded at the moment. I have couple of images. So I need to get total size of images, add up total loaded and divide whatever is loaded by total.

Comment: Yeah, right, for this you have to track all the loader objects, record their `bytesLoaded` in an array of ints corresponding to loaders, and sum that up. See update.

Comment: I was summing up `e.bytesLoaded` for every load object `total_loaded_bytes += event.bytesLoaded`. Why do I need to put the bytesLoaded into a `progress` array?

Comment: Also, is this `total_bytes += bmp.getPixels(bmp.rect).length` a wrong way to get total bytes of bitmaps? If not, what is the right way?

Comment: First, say you are uploading a something that's 1024 kilobytes long, but the channel is too small so the throughput is 1 kilobyte per frame. You will receive 1024 events with 1024*i bytes in `bytesLoaded` for each, and if you add these values up, you'll end up with 512 megabytes instead of one. And second, yes it's the right way to get **raw** bitmap weight, but if you encode it via say `PNGEncoder`, the resultant ByteArray will be way smaller. Also raw bitmaps can only be assigned within Flash, you will have to do tricks to read raw data outside Flash.